# How to create a dialog in WPF like the inspect variable dialog in in VS 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, visual-studio-2010, window

I would like to create a temporary dialog similar to the one Visual Studio 2010 shows when you hover in Debug Mode over a variable. You can expand into the contents of the object and a windows opens that can reach over the borders of the edit window. When the mouse leaves the border of this temporary window, it closes automatically.

I do not intend to write a debugger, I am just intersted in the technique used to create this kind of temporary window.

Does anyone know how this is done in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some good success with the Adorner system in WPF. It allows you to bung an overlay virtually anywhere.

Check out the MSDN here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx

Previously, I have created an adorner to follow the mouse during a DragDrop, to show the information I'm dragging (like dragging from iTunes).

At a guess for your program, you could capture the hover and create an adorner rather like a ToolTip.